# Citrix Receiver Kiosk App "Unsupported chrome app origin detected"

Tags: google-chrome, citrix, google-chrome-os

I searched all over and couldn't find my specific issue here so please excuse me if my search-fu has failed me. 

My issue:

I am currently trying to create a kiosk app for my company's chromeboxes. I have the application packaged and published privately on the chrome web store. I get the app to load but once I launch the kiosk app and enter in my company's url I am presented with, "Unsupported Chrome App Origin Detected". The only thing I can find so far about this is to run the flag --disable-web-security. I can only find examples for Windows/Mac/Linux plus that isn't secure. Am I missing something in my Default.cr or manifest.json files? Is this even possible? This is on a vanilla chromebox that isn't part of a Google Apps domain. Do I need to have it added to a Google Apps for Work domain to get this to work? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting the url? Are you setting it to a webview? Some relevant code would really help...

Answer (score 0):

Please add your generated chrome extension app id to storefront web.config file. Please have a look at http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/receiver/chrome/1-7/receiver-chrome-deploy.html point 8 at the end on how to do it.

Also please use 1.7 as it supports better Kiosk mode integration.